# How to submit a form in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, post

I have following action to display a form

```
public function showformAction() {  
   $this->view->form = new Form_MyForm();
   $this->view->form->setAction( 'submitform' );
}
```

above action shows a form successfully with only one textarea and submit button.

And I am using following action to submit above form:

```
public function submitformAction() {

    $form = new Form_MyForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

      if ( $request->isPost() ) {
           $values = $form->getValues();
           print_r($values);die();      
      } else {
           echo 'Invalid Form'; 
      }
}
```

Above action is showing following output:

```
Array ( [myfield] => )
```

It means it is not posting values correctly and always shows empty array or I am not getting posted values correctly. How to post values to submitformAction().

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must use the `isValid()` before accessing the values of a submitted form, because it's right there that the values are checked and valorized

```
public function submitformAction() {

    $form = new Form_MyForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

      if ( $request->isPost() ) {
          if ($form->isValid( $request->getPost() )) {
              $values = $form->getValues();
              print_r($values);die();     
          } 
      } else {
           echo 'Invalid Form'; 
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But use `$request->getPost()` instead of `$_POST` where you are checking isValid();  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In complement to @VAShhh response. With some more details:
You need to do two things, populate your form fields with the POSTed data and applying security filters and validators to that data. Zend_Form provides one simple function which perform both, it's `isValid($data)`.

So you should:

1. build your form
2. test you are in a POST request
3. populate & filter & validate this data
4. either handle the fact in can be invalid and re-show the form wich is now
   decorated with Errors **OR** retrieve valid data from the form

So you should get:

```
function submitformAction() {
    $form = new Form_MyForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ( $request->isPost() ) {
        if (!$form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            $this->view->form = $form;
            // here maybe you could connect to the same view script as your first action
            // another solution is to use only one action for showform & submitform actions
            // and detect the fact it's not a post to do the showform part
        } else {
            // values are secure if filters are on each form element
            // and they are valid if all validators are set
            $securizedvalues = $form->getValues();
            // temporary debug
            print_r($securizedvalues);die();
            // here the nice thing to do at the end, after the job is quite
            // certainly a REDIRECT with a code 303 (Redirect after POSt)      
            $redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
            $redirector->setCode(303)
              ->setExit(true)
              ->setGotoSimple('newaction','acontroller','amodule');
            $redirector->redirectAndExit();
    } else {
           throw new Zend_Exception('Invalid Method'); 
    }
}
```

And as said in the code re-showing the form you shoudl really try to use the same function for both showing and handling POST as a lot of steps are really the same:

- building the form
- showing it in the view in case of errors

By detecting the request is a POST you can detect you are in the POST handling case.